# Is there any chance for .ipa file size expansion

Tags: xcode4.3

Any one please help me....In our project, we have lot of videos may be 84 videos(its compressed zip folder size is 2 GB). We can put it in web services....
   But we found, In android, there is an option called .apk file expansion. ie., we can put your app + compressed zipped video folder file into google play. when user play any video in app, it will be downloaded to mobile memory. We have to write code to play video from mobile memory....
   something like this is in .ipa file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 6 introduced hosted content, but only for In-App-Purchases: "Host In-App Purchase content on Apple’s servers, so you can easily add, manage, and deliver In-App Purchase content for your app."